# Somar na consulta MYSQL em campo varchar eliminando Strings

Tags: mysql, mysqli, sum

Como somar direto na consulta *MYSQL* quando o campo é *varchar* e necessita eliminar algumas strings.

Exemplo:

```
+------------+
|valor_total |
+------------+ 
|R$ 2.277,90 | 
|R$ 3.217,30 | 
|R$ 9.857,40 | 
+------------+
```

A tentativa abaixo me retorna soma = 0

```
SELECT REPLACE(valor_total, 'R$', ''), SUM(valor_total) AS TotalDaSoma FROM carrinho WHERE representante_id='92'
```

Comment: Minha nossa senhora, "que campo" bicho! Por que não usam um `decimal` ao menos, e formatação faz pela aplicação ou na própria query? Isso aí está um caos.

Comment: Eu não pedi opinião lógica ou estética e sim solução para pergunta , mesmo assim obrigado !

Comment: Então você não entendeu o conceito do SO. Se você só quer jogar pergunta e ter a resposta pronta, está fazendo errado. Mas boa sorte aí! ✌

Comment: Você poderia fazer sua crítica apresentando uma resposta! Não é sempre que um cliente quer atualizar seu algoritmo e é esse caso, onde eu preciso resolver o problema com esses recursos.  O que você disse é o óbvio, acho que você que não entende o conceito da plataforma.

Comment: Já tem 2 respostas, muito boas. Eu coloquei no comentário exatamente para acrescentar. O que eu disse é óbvio, mas como não tem motivo do uso dessa forma, não tem como eu advinhar. E se eu que não entendo o conceito, então quem criou esse campo entende de que? ... Que complicação por uma simples dica né!?

Comment: Sim não vamos ficar discutindo, todos tem seus entendimentos ! Eu entendo o que você quis dizer também, mas no fim todo mundo fica satisfeito, uns com respostas outros com pontuações ! Acho que importante são as pessoas participar!

Comment: Com certeza! A ideia era ajudar, se a forma de falar soou agressiva, peço desculpas! E precisando, estamos aí! ✌

Comment: Sim, se precisar também estamos ai !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisa somar o valor convertido:

- remover o R$,
- remover o ponto dos milhares
- substituir a vírgula por ponto

Depois disso converter para número e somar:

```
SELECT SUM(
cast(
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
       REPLACE(valor_total, 'R$ ', '') /* REMOVE R$*/
      , '.',''),   /* REMOVE O PONTO */
     ',','.')      /* TROCA A VÍRGULA POR PONTO */
        as decimal(8,2))
)  AS TotalDaSoma
FROM carrinho 
WHERE representante_id='92'
```

Quebrei em linhas para facilitar o entendimento.

Aqui um fiddle demonstrando a conversão funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d2ca4/4

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

É necessário encadear as funções, deixando a que deve ser executada primeiro dentro da que deve ser executada por último, no seu caso ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT SUM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(valor_total, '.', ''), ',', '.'), ' ', ''), 'R$', '')) AS TotalDaSoma
FROM carrinho
WHERE representante_id='92'
```

Dessa forma serão executadas as seguintes funções:

- Substituir `.` por `nada`;
- Substituir `,` por `.`;
- Substituir `espaço` por `nada`;
- Substituir `R$` por `nada`;

[Clique aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c8686/1) para ver um exemplo funcionando.

Comment: Obrigado a sua também funciona, escolhi a outra pois já converte pra decimal !